# Can I reference a .NET 3.5 .DLL in a 4.0 app?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, compatibility

The subject says it all... If I've got a .NET 4.0 app, can I add a reference to 2.0/3.0/3.5 .DLL? I don't have VS2010 installed so I can't check myself (I'm doing research at the moment).

I've tried to find information on both on SO and Google, but I get conflicting answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can - but if it's a mixed mode assembly (i.e. contains a mixture of native code and .NET code) then I believe that can cause problems. (IIRC the MySql driver had this problem recently, and devs had to rebuild under .NET 4 to get it to work.)